# A different method to check if an element is even in matlab?

Tags: matlab

**This was the original question:**

Write a script that asks the user for two positive numbers a and b and calculates the sum of the even numbers in the range [a,b]. The script should print a message with the range and the sum values as shown in the example below.

Enter the first number of the range: 3

Enter the last number of the range: 12

The sum of the even numbers in the range [3,12] is 40

---

**I was able to solve it using the Rem function**

```
a=input('Enter the first number of the range: ',d);

b=input('Enter the last number of the range: ',d);

m=0

For i=a:b;

    If rem(i,2)=0

    m=i+m;

    End

End

fprintf('The sum of the even numbers in the range [%d,%d] is %d\n',a,b,m)
```

**My question is**, since I knew about the Rem function I was able to solve it. How does one do this without knowing the Rem function, and this brought up another question. What if they wanted me to list the prime numbers, what is the method of check in that case?

Comment: You can always find out whether such a function exists by searching the documentation...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways to check if a number is even or not

here is one alternative:

```
round(number/2) == (number/2)
```

Sample 1

```
>> number

number =

81

>> ans

ans =

 0
```

Sample 2

```
>> number

number =

92

>> ans

ans =

 1
```

There is also an inbuilt function ( [isprime](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/isprime.html) ) for checking if a number is prime or not

Example from mathworks:

```
>> isprime([2 3 0 6 10])

ans =

 1     1     0     0     0
```

Answer (score 3):

How about just

```
if ~mod(a,2)
    m = sum(a:2:b)
else
    m = sum(a+1:2:b)
end
```

In this case mod is only used to check only a. This is the only check that is needed

Answer (score 1):

For the sum of even numbers, you could use:

```
numbers = 2*(ceil(a/2):floor(b/2)); %// even numbers in the given range
result = sum(numbers);
```

To save operations, you can multiply by `2` only at the end:

```
result = 2*sum((ceil(a/2):floor(b/2)));
```

Or compute the result directly:

```
x = ceil(a/2);
y = floor(b/2);
result = (y+x)*(y-x+1);
```